# React admin build issue("react-admin": "^4.16.11",)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, react-admin

i am using react admin in nextjs project i have created all components and in data provider i call the Graphql API (query and mutation) it work fine locally but when i try to make build they through issues i write Yarn buid

```
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.21
$ next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
   Generating static pages (3/5)  [==  ] 
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12265
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:14147
    at Object.ns [as useMemo] (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:40843)
    at t.useMemo (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109391)
    at eg (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12184)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12265
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:14147
    at Object.ns [as useMemo] (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:40843)
    at t.useMemo (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109391)
    at eg (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12184)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
 ✓ Generating static pages (5/5) 

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /page: /
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

i am try to make build using yarn build but see this issue

```
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.21
$ next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
   Generating static pages (3/5)  [==  ] 
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12265
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:14147
    at Object.ns [as useMemo] (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:40843)
    at t.useMemo (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109391)
    at eg (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12184)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12265
    at /home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:14147
    at Object.ns [as useMemo] (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:40843)
    at t.useMemo (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109391)
    at eg (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/.next/server/app/page.js:73:12184)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (/home/eritheia/projects/criclay-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
 ✓ Generating static pages (5/5) 

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /page: /
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

i want to make build successfully